# Area of a triangle using determinants of side lengths (not coordinates of vertices)

Tags: determinant, triangles, area

> Given the side lengths of a triangle (and not the coordinates of vertices) is there a way to find the area of a triangle using determinants?

For example, if the three side lengths are $a$, $b$, and $c$ then the area could be easily found by the Heron's formula. $A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s= \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Is there a way to find the area of this triangle using determinants?

Comment: yes, just add another point to make a parallelogram then half the value of determinent is the are of triangle.

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question, but I would like to then generalize the question to find the area of a parallelogram using determinants when its side lengths are given.

Comment: Yes, we have
$\small 16 A^2 = -\left|\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & c^2 & b^2\\
1 & c^2 & 0 & a^2\\
1 & b^2 & a^2 & 0\end{matrix}\right|$,
See [Cayley Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) for details.

Comment: @achillehui $$16A^{2}={\begin{vmatrix}2a^{2}&a^{2}+b^{2}-c^{2}\\a^{2}+b^{2}-c^{2}&2b^{2}\end{vmatrix}}$$

Comment: @rohitt As for [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891066/area-of-a-triangle-using-determinants-of-side-lengths-not-coordinates-of-vertic#comment8024767_3891066), how about a special case of parallelogram – a rhombus with sides lengths $a$ and $a$...?

Comment: @achille hui Please transform your comment as "the" answer, maybe by saying that in fact, it is a version of Heron's formula put to the square.

Comment: @CiaPan For a rhombus with side length $a$ and height $h$, the area is $a.h$, I'm not sure how $h$ can be described in terms of $a$

Comment: @rohitt That's a problem: it _can't_. And a rhombus can have _any_ area from zero to $a^2$, depending on angles between its sides (flattened to a line segment or a square, respectively). Similarly, a parallelogram with sides' lengths $a$ and $b$ can have any area from zero (when degenerated to a line segment) to $a\cdot b$ (when it is a rectangle).